# Is it possible to use Unity as the DI framework used in conjunction with Restier

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, .net-4.8, restier

I've been working with WebApi in conjunction with Odata for a service and that was moving forward nicely. Then I came across the Restier project, which appears to fit in quite well with what I'm doing.
However, I was using Microsoft Unity for my DI support and would like to continue to do so, but I can't seem to find any information on doing so in conjunction with Restier.

It appears (looking at the source) that Restier defaults internally to using a default DI framework. From what I've seen online, it should be swappable, but I've had no luck doing so.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Is this a .NET Core app? RESTier doesn't seem to have been updated for a long time, I'd be hesitant to use it.

Comment: My apologies. It's .net framework, not core. I'll update the ask.
From what I can tell, Restier does appear to still be active. There were updates to the project here as of just 4 days ago

https://github.com/OData/RESTier